# Can I use a String resource to generate the deeplink in a Jetpack Navigation XML file?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

Let's say I have the following `buildType` section in my Gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        resValue "string", "DEEPLINK_EXAMPLE", "appnamedebug://detail/{detail_id}"
        ...
    }
    release {
        ...
        resValue "string", "DEEPLINK_EXAMPLE", "appname://detail/{detail_id}"
        ...
    }
  }
```

I wanted to use the generated String resource as a deeplink in my Jetpack Navigation XML file as follows:

```
<deepLink app:uri="@string/DEEPLINK_EXAMPLE" />
```

I've tried something similar to this, but the Intent Filters don't show up when I looked at the output file from `./adb shell dumpsys package r`.

Is this even possible in the first place? If it is, is there something I missed?

Comment: does [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) help? Seems to be doable if you define the [argument](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#define_destination_arguments) linking to the `R.string` and then uri could use the argument

Comment: I don't think the fragment's argument, even with a default value, can be used as the URI of a Deeplink.

Answer (score 3):

That method in the question just leads to the manifest having the intent filter as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="string" />
    <data android:path="/DEEPLINK_EXAMPLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I guess it's a pipe dream then.

Well, in the end I had to resort to the previous method: copying the Navigation Graphs to the debug and release source sets and set the deeplink URIs there accordingly.

So the Nav Graph in the `debug` source set would have this:

`<deepLink app:uri="appnamedebug://detail/{detail_id}" />`

While the Nav Graph in the `release` source set would have this:

`<deepLink app:uri="appname://detail/{detail_id}" />`

I'm actually not sure whether to keep the Nav Graph in the `main` source code, or remove it so the ones in the `debug`/`release` source sets have precedence.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

The previous answer says everything, but for clarity I want to add this example:

If you add to `nav_graph`:

```
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/myLink"
    app:uri="@string/my_link_uri"
/>
```

It will be naively processed in the merged manifest as:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:host="string" />
    <data android:path="/my_link_uri" />
</intent-filter>
```

Therefore illustrating that string resources are not parsed correctly by the Navigation component.